# Rename default rendered headings like "Example" in Swift Markup language

Tags: swift, markup, swift-playground

Raw Markup

[image]

Rendered Markup

[image]

How do I change the word `Example` in the "Rendered Markup" to anything I would like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Custom callouts

You can make use of a [Custom Callout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/CustomCallouts.html)

```
/*:
 # Hello, playground!

 The print() function in Swift
 
 * callout(Custom Title):
    print("Hello, playground!")
 
*/
```

Rendered as (using Dusk theme)

[image]

---

#### Additional pre-defined callouts

If you don't fancy the color of the Custom Callout, there are a few other callouts (in addition to Example) available for use in a playground

```
/*:
 # Hello, playground!

 The print() function in Swift
 
 * Example:
    print("Hello, playground!")
 
 * Experiment:
    print("Hello, playground!")
 
 * Important:
    print("Hello, playground!")
 
 * Note:
    print("Hello, playground!")
 
*/
```

[image]

For additional details, see [the Markup Formatting Reference - Markup Functionality](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html).

Comment: How were you able to change the colors?

Comment: @Eric The color of each callout is fixed and can, as far as I know, not be changed (same no matter which theme you use: you can change between themes in _Xcode -> Preferences: Fonts & Colors_). E.g. the _Custom Callout_ is always colored cyan, whereas the _Experiment_ callout is colored magenta, and so on.