# How to change or remove "Example" label on markdown rendered code block in playgrounds?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, xcplayground

In Xcode Playgrounds, it is possible to write markdown and render the markdown properly using the `Editor -> Show Rendered Markup` option. In the markdown of the playgrounds, code blocks can be formatted by enclosing them with: ```` ``` ````

However, when the formatted code is being rendered like this, the Playground adds a label **`Example`** in the rendered version. Does anyone know how to change or remove that label?

````
 *Optionals* are simply `enum`s that either contain a generic value of type `T` or not:
 ```
 enum Optional<T> {
   case none
   case some(T)
 }
 ```
````

Is being rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Markdown renderers are not usually customizable, and I doubt that Apple's is in this case either.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38923167/6541007)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename default rendered headings like "Example" in Swift Markup language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923167/rename-default-rendered-headings-like-example-in-swift-markup-language)